# Convert CGPDFPageRef to integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I need convert a `CGPDFPageRef` var to an integer , I create an `if` statement that checks if the PDF pages are  less or greater than than the file doesn't show it.

```
- (id) setUpPDF: (int) pageNumber {    

//** = I need some integer that automatically detects PDF pages
    if ((pageNumber < **) || (pageNumber > **)) return nil;


 CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(),


                                              CFSTR("test"),
                                              CFSTR("pdf"), NULL);


    myDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
    myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocumentRef, pageNumber);
```

Comment: Your question in unclear. Do you need to get the total number of pages? i.e. CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocumentRef)?

Comment: Yes , but How can I equal CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages with an integer?

Comment: using the == operator, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total number of pages using `CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocumentRef)`.

`CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages()` returns a size_t, which is un unsigned integer. You can compare this directly with an integer type.

So for your code snippet above, I assume you want something like:

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("test"), CFSTR("pdf"), NULL);
myDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
// take note that pdf page numbering starts at 1
if ((pageNumber < 1) || (pageNumber > CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocumentRef))) return nil;
```

I suggest changing your parameter from `(int)pageNumber` to `(size_t)pageNumber` though.